# Overriding Bootstrap .navbar border-color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootsrap, I want to change the border color of the navbar. Using classes and adding an id tag didn't work. Adding `!important` is the only way I came up with. Is there a better way?

```css
.navbar {
    border-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top border">
</nav>
```

Comment: Why you want to override the class? if you want to add some styles in it then write your own class

Comment: maybe i should have used "to change the border color"

Comment: What's wrong with using `!important`?

Comment: ıt's the first time i use bootstrap actually, if it's ok to use "!important" then it's fine with me:)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to edit the bootstrap classes by making a new stylesheet and naming your classes the same.

https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/